# Print a loop of string output

Tags: python, passwords, word-list

I have a code that print random alpha numeric password. But only one. I aim to print a 1000 line of passwords.

The function is :

```
get_random_alpahanumeric_string(letters_count,digits_count)
```

I tried this but in vain:

```
String_to_iterate = get_random_alpahanumeric_string(letters_count,digits_count) 
for s in range(1,10000): 
    if i >= s: 
        s == i
        break 
    i += 1 
    print(String_to_iterate)
```

Please any help.

Comment: `String_to_iterate` isn't `string_to_iterate`; `i` isn't `I`; and what is `s == I` intended to do?

Comment: Even after your edit it's unclear where `i` comes from and why you use it here. Did you mix up some funny ideas about a `while` loop with the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Call the function in the loop.

```
for _ in range(1000):
    print(get_random_alpahanumeric_string(letters_count,digits_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

To print a thousand random passwords, you need to call the method a thousands time

For that, put the call inside the loop:

```
for i in range(1000):
    string_to_iterate = get_random_alpahanumeric_string(letters_count,digits_count) 
    print(string_to_iterate)
```